# Valores monetários com asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Estou enfrentando dificuldade em trabalhar com valores monetários (decimais), utilizando aplicação web, `asp.net MVC`, com banco de dados **Mysql**. O problema é que não consigo editar valores decimais, como: **53,50**, ou **53.50**. Não consigo salvar utilizando ponto, nem vírgula. O problema também consiste em dizer que o web.config, já está configurado o *globalization* com **pt-BR**.

Segue o model:

```
[DisplayName("Preço:")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public Nullable<decimal> preco { get; set; }
```

Segue a view:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.preco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) 
     <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.preco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "somente numeros" } })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.preco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

**Web.config:**

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Conforme a questão que foi comparada com duplicada, a solução da mesma infelizmente não contempla a minha questão.

Comment: Vamos reabrir, aí respondo pra você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instale na sua aplicação o pacote NuGet [jQuery Money Mask](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JQuery.MoneyMask/).

[Veja exemplos de uso e configuração aqui](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/).

Evite usar `@Html.EditorFor()`. Ele não permite máscara nem adição de classes porque é definido como um *template*. Troque para:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.preco, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "somente números" })
```

Ainda assim, se você quer usar `@Html.EditorFor()`. funciona da seguinte forma:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.preco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "somente números" }})
```